# Matlab-Operation in a given column in a cell matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell matrix where the first 'column' has strings and second 'column' has numbers. Suppose I want to do the same operation in the second column. If this cell matrix was a common matrix I could do:

```
   matrix(:,2)=matrix(:,2)*100;
```

But I don't know how to do it in a cell matrix, it gives me errors when I tried it in different ways:

```
>> BKS{:,2}=BKS{:,2}*100
   Error using  * 
   Too many input arguments.

>> BKS(:,2)=BKS(:,2)*100
   Undefined function 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

How to do this operation with matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide alternatives:

```
BKS(:,2) = num2cell(100*[BKS{:,2}].');
```

or

```
BKS(:,2) = cellfun(@times, BKS(:,2), repmat({100}, size(BKS,1),1), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cellfun` (which is basically looping)

```
BKS(:,2) = cellfun(@(x)(x*100),BKS(:,2))
```